# Image rotation issue (horizontal picture uploading as vertical) -- Exif issue?

Tags: php, functions, images

I am building a classifieds site on WordPress where users can upload their ads/images from front-end. However, when horizontal pictures are uploaded, they upload as vertical.

I looked into the issue and found the following suggested solution for fixing image orientation using its Exif data:

```
//read EXIF header from uploaded file
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);

//fix the Orientation if EXIF data exist
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
    case 8:
        $createdImage = imagerotate($image,90,0);
        break;
    case 3:
        $createdImage = imagerotate($image,180,0);
        break;
    case 6:
        $createdImage = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
        break;
}
}
```

I placed this in my WP theme's `functions.php` file but this did not solve my issue. Unfortunately I don't have enough code knowledge at all to figure out what is wrong with this. I would really appreciate any advice/input.

Comment: _All_ of the pictures? _Some_ of the pictures? Could you provide an example of image that uploads wrong?

Comment: Rarst, thank you for your response. All of my horizontal pictures (taken on my Android phone) were showing up vertical. However, I was able to solve this problem by installing plugin "Image Rotation Repair". (The "Image Rotation Fixer" plugin did not work for me.) Thank you for your support!

Comment: You should add that as an answer so that others can benefit from it. :) Maybe with a bit of detail on _what_ plugin is doing to address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

summersummer solved the problem reported by installing the [Image Rotation Repair](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-repair/), which describes itself as follows:

> The Image Rotation Repair plugin simply fixes image orientation based
>   on EXIF data. This is primarily a patch for mis-oriented images
>   delivered from iPhones. Functionally it filters all uploads and if
>   EXIF->Orientation is set to a number greater than 1, then the image is
>   resaved with a new orientation before the image is processed by
>   WordPress.

Comment: Also worth noting is that there is a trac ticket about that which is aimed to be solved at 4.8

Comment: Excellent! Looks like it's [#37140](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37140)